# How do I use .htaccess to lock one directory but password protect another?

Tags: .htaccess

As an example, lets say I have 5 directories. 3 of the 5 I don't want indexed via a browser, the 4th I want accessible via a password only and the 5th I don't need to be locked and can be accessible via a browser. How do I achieve this with the httd.conf file?

I know I'll need .htaccess/.htpasswd files in the directory I want password protected, I'll need to remove Indexing from the Options directive so those 3 directories are not accessible.

But I'm lost as to how to get the 1 directory viewable publicly, with the other two settings in place. Someone please help! Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem ? `.htaccess` apply to the directory they are on.

Comment: I want to remove indexing from all directories via a browser except for 2. Of the 2, I need to put a password on one, and the other I want to be open to all. How do I achieve this? 1. remove indexes from the options directive, 2. put the .htaccess & .htpasswd in the director I want protected, but how do I achieve #3 (leaving that one directory open to all?

Answer (score 0):

This looks straightforward to me, but since you don't give much details, I have to make some assumptions and I might be wrong.

- I'm assuming all your directories are directly under your `DocumentRoot` and not nested one inside the other.
- You have the default configuration, no changes to `AllowOverride` or `Options` directives in your main server or `VirtualHost` configurations.
- Apache version 2.4

Also, you mention both the main `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess` so I'm going to give you just the config for the main `httpd.conf` file.

```
# Don't AutoIndex dir1, dir2 or dir3
<DirectoryMatch "/path/document/root/dir(1|2|3)$">
    Options -Indexes
</DirectoryMatch>

# Protect dir4
<Directory "/path/document/root/dir4">
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "private"
    # Adjust for the location of your htpasswd. DONT put it inside your DocumentRoot
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/example.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# This directive isn't necessary at all provided you didn't change defaults
<Directory "/path/document/root/dir5">
    Options +Indexes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```